# kivy widget is not displayed

Tags: python, kivy

I wanted to make a small program with an widget containing an image, which changes the image when you click on it, but when I ran the program it did not displayed the widget.
Instead it displayed an empty, screen, but with the correct backgroundcolor.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

kv_string = Builder.load_string('''
<Root>:
    Feld:
        pos_hint: {"right": 1, 'top': 1}
        id: a1

<Feld>:
    Image:
        pos: root.pos
        id: my_image
        source: root.weg

    
''')

class Root(FloatLayout):
    kr = StringProperty('kreuz.png')
    ks = StringProperty('kreis.png')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Root, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.Update, 1/60.)
    def Update(self, *args):
        pass

class Feld(Widget):
    weg = StringProperty('hinterg.png')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Feld, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.Update, 1/60.)
    def Update(self, *args):
        pass
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.ids.my_image.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.weg = self.parent.kr
            

class TTT(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (0, 1, 1, 1)
        return kv_string

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TTT().run()
```

Comment: I've new to kivy, but I made some progress by replacing `return kv_string` with `return Root()`

Answer (score 1):

Your root widget is kv_string, which is None since the variable is the result of Builder.load_string on a string that doesn't contain a root widget.

Comment: why isn't Root() the root widget?

Comment: Because you didn't set it to be? The result of your load_string call is None.